# Definition of quadratic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

What is a quadratic equation and what is its simplified and cannonic form?

Comment: See [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/quadratic-equation.html).

Comment: I didnt get which one was tha canonic form and which one was the simplified

Comment: See this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quadratic equation (in one variable) is a polynomial equation $P(x)=0$, where $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree 2.

The canonical form of a quadratic equation is $ax^2+bx+c=0$. The simplified form I'm not sure about, but I'm guessing $x^2+bx+c=0$ (obtained from canonical by dividing both sides by the coefficient of $x^2$).

Comment: @user1038739 terminology: the *simplified* polynomial $x^2 + \dfrac{b}{a} x + \dfrac{c}{a}$ is also known as the *monic associate*.

Comment: Maybe "simplified" is in the eye of the beholder, but I consider the form where the square is "completed" to be simple. That is, $$a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4a}$$

Answer (score 3):

Quadratics are usually written in the following three ways:

**Expanded form**

This form is written canonically as

$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$

This is a very general form and it is easy to find $f(0)$ if needed.  However, finding the roots are a bit more difficult.

**Factored form**

This form is written as

$$f(x)=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$$

This form is very convenient if you need the roots of $f(x)$, as they are simply $x_1$ and $x_2$.

**Vertex Form (complete the square)**

This form is written as

$$f(x)=a(x-h)^2+k$$

This form is convenient for finding the vertex $(h, k)$.  This is the form that is used to derive the quadratic formula.

Expanded form is usually considered to be the most basic form, so this is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A quadratic equation is, in laymen's terms, a "curve". However, there is much more to it than that. Each quadratic has a degree(the highest power), a leading coefficient(the first coefficient), and a constant(the number without a variable). Quadratic equations can be factored in several ways. This is the AC method:

```
               ax^2 + bx + c = d -> factors of ac that add to b ->
     ax^2 + f_1(b)x + f_2(b)x + c = d where f_1 is factor 1 and f_2 is factor two ->
       gcf(ax^2 + f_1(b)x)•(gx + h) + gcf(f_2(b)x + c)•(gx + h) = d -> 
    At this point ax + b = bx + c, they should read the same.
    (gcf(ax^2 + f_1(b)x)+gcf(f_2(b)x + c))(gx + h) = d
```

Answer (score 0):

In Algebra, Equation with the highest degree 2 is a **quadratic equation**. And its simplest form is 
$$
ax^2+bx+cx = 0,
$$ 
where $x$ represents variable and $a$,$b$, and $c$ represents constant or numbers. Also, $a$ should not be equals to zero because if $a = 0$ then the equation will become a linear one. And its graphical representation is a parabolic shape.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers.